# Using size classes programmatically

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, ios8, size-classes

I (hopefully) watched all the relevant WWDC2014 session videos and read the docs, so this question is mostly to confirm my suspicions, but please educate me.

What I want to do is animate views using Auto Layout. That in itself is not a problem. But these animations' endpoints change with different orientations. I thought I might be able to use size classes to move the views automatically on rotation, but Apple's developer guide says that animations have to be done programmatically, and from what I can gather, size classes are an Interface-Builder-only thing.

Another idea I had was using custom layout guides like the top/bottom ones IB provides, but those seem to be hardcoded.

The last thing I could do is update constraints by hand after listening to rotation events, but that is nothing new, and I feel like size classes should be useable for more than just static interfaces. Am I overestimating their purpose?

**TLDR:** Given two points A and B that a view can have its origin at (due to animations), how can I move both points using size classes or something similar?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After some more digging in the docs I have finally found something useable. The `UIContentContainer` protocol defines `willTransitionToTraitCollection(:withTransitionCoordinator:)`, and that method's first parameter (a `UITraitCollection`) contains horizontal and vertical size classes as well as a `UIUserInterfaceIdiom` (that can be used to know whether the app is running on a iPhone or iPad, although size classes should be used for most things).

Additionally, since iOS 8 hides the status bar in landscape view, `traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection:)` is the corresponding method that gets called after the change happened, so the value of `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden` has changed when this method is called. Can be useful for `UIScrollView`'s `contentInset` for example.

Lastly, if you need the exact screen sizes (in points, of course, but the above mentioned trait collection also knows about pixel density), there is `viewWillTransitionToSize(:withTransitionCoordinator:)`.

Hope this helps someone else as well.

Comment: Do you have any idea when will this method traitCollectionDidChange() in my UIView subclass be called?

Comment: If I remember correctly: After the device was rotated. The rotated views are laid out, and then the transition animation (=rotation animation) happens.