# How to properly use size classes when building the UI programmatically (using SnapKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, size-classes, masonry-ios-osx

I have decided to create my UI programmatically as oppose to storyboards to avoid merge conflict nightmares and a few other things. However, I'm running to a few problems:

1. How would I do size classes?
2. My `viewDidLoad` methods are usually very large which reduces the readability of the code. Any suggestions or best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) [Using size classes programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466554/using-size-classes-programmatically),
 [Programmatically implementing two different layouts using size classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685829/programmatically-implementing-two-different-layouts-using-size-classes),
http://www.digistarters.com/swift-autolayout-and-size-classes-programmatically 
2) Constraints may take a big place in your viewDidLoad method if you create all of this programmatically. I moved from fully-coded-UI to xibs and storyboards couple of years ago, and now my life much easier.
Also, when view controller becomes too long, you can try this methodology [Viper.](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/)

Comment: I actually like your suggestion, like majority of my code is the table view cells which can be xibs I suppose.